# GET ServletContext in ServiceLayer

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

What is the best practice to get servlet context in service layer ?

Comment: The best practice is 'do not do this' - a service layer should be agnostic of the client applicaiton implementation details and protocols.

Comment: Whatever you need from the ServletContext, you need to extract it beforehand and pass exactly *that* to the service layer.

Comment: thanks, i will pass my required object as argumnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options, all of them wrong:

- Put it in a `ThreadLocal` (i.e. per-request) and get it via `ThreadLocalServletContextHolder.get()`
- Pass it as an argument to service methods

They are wrong, because the service layer should not know that it's servlets that are supplying it with data. Tomorrow it might be swing.

So the correct way is to gather all required parameters in the servlet (or controller), and pass them as arguments to the service layer. A worse option, but still not that bad is to get the `Map` of attribute and pass it instead.

Comment: "Pass it as an argument to service methods" [...] "So the correct way is to gather all required parameters in the servlet (or controller), and pass them as arguments to the service layer". Excuse me, sir, but could you please explain the difference between the 1st and the 2nd statement and maybe provide an example? Thank you.